# How to print a box outline in assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

Please I am new assembly language and I am trying to print the outline of a box. I am really stuck. tried everything I know but I just can't get it to print the outline. Thank you in advance for your help

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

    .data
    prompt BYTE "This program draws a rectangle using the * character.", 0
    len BYTE "How high would you like your box? ", 0
    wid BYTE "How wide would you like your box?: ", 0
    image BYTE "* ", 0
    space BYTE " ", 0
    leninput DWORD ?
    widinput DWORD ?
    h  DWORD ?
    w DWORD ?
    count DWORD ?


    .code
    main proc

    ;;; Write the prompt to the screen
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    ;;; Write the length request to the screen
    mov edx, OFFSET len
    call Crlf
    call WriteString


    ;;; Obtain the length value(which will be in eax)
    call ReadDec
    mov leninput, eax

    ;;; Write the width request to the screen
    mov edx, OFFSET wid
    call Crlf
    call WriteString


    ;;; Obtain the second value(which will be in eax)
    call ReadDec
    mov widinput, eax


    ;;; Draw rectangle on screen
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, leninput; set outer loop with length


    L1 :
     mov count, ecx; save outer loop count
     mov ecx, widinput; set inner loop count with the width

     L2 :
     call ConditionCheck

    loop L2; repeat the inner loop
    call Crlf; Print line
        mov ecx, count; restore outer loop(length)
    loop L1; repeat outer loop 1

    exit
main endp
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
ConditionCheck PROC
mov eax, leninput
mov ebx, widinput

.IF eax == 1
mov edx, OFFSET image
call WriteString
.ELSEIF eax == leninput
mov edx, OFFSET image
call WriteString
.ELSEIF ebx == 1
mov edx, OFFSET image
call WriteString
.ELSEIF ebx == widinput
mov edx, OFFSET image
call WriteString
.ELSE
mov edx, OFFSET space
call WriteString
.ENDIF
ret
ConditionCheck ENDP
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -

end main
```

Output should look like:

```
How high would you like your box? 5
How wide would you like your box? 6
******
*    *
*    *
*    *
******
```

But I am having the box filled in instead

Comment: Ah.. MASM macros or directives, or what that `.IF` is... that must be inconvenient to debug, to not see the real instructions. BTW, did you consider what would happen, if you would do `leninput -= 2;`, output one full line always, then do `leninput` loop with "inner" lines, and after loop would finish, output one full line again? (But you should probably sanitize input to verify it was 3+) .... and similarly the inner part code may be simpler to do after `widinput -= 2;` treatment.

Answer (score 0):

`image` and `space` should have the same amount of characters:

```
image BYTE "* ", 0
space BYTE "  ", 0
```

In the procedure `ConditionCheck` `EAX`and `EBX` refer to the **current** values of the loops **not** to the unchangeable values of `leninput` and `widinput`. So change

```
mov eax, leninput
mov ebx, widinput
```

to

```
mov eax, count
mov ebx, ecx
```